# In a post transform to entities the tags that are not allowed and keep the tags allowed

Tags: php, post, htmlspecialchars

I have a form where an user can post a global notice into the system (for other users to see).
The system outputs HTML directly from the DB (when a user wanto to see a notice).
I'd like to allow some html tags to stay intact and to have the rest of them with htmlspecialchars() applied.
I already tried to apply

```
 str_replace($search, $replace, htmlspecialchars($str))
```

strategy but it seems to be really slow. Too slow, actually. And also it's not safe that will always work, Is there an alternative for this?
I wanted something that did the strip_tags() job except that it, instead of striping tags it would apply htmlspecialchars to the not allowed tags.

ADD(ed) info (by request):
$str can be any size you can think of. I thought of using a big string (1M characters (generated rendomly with some allowed and some unallowed tags inside. All tags had attributes) for the reason of testing one of the worst case scenarios With the logic: If it works like this, it should work for simpler cases.
The server took 5s to process the complete str_replace (with htmlspecialchars). This test was made in my computer that has 2GHz CPU and DDR3 RAM.
both $search and $replace have a total of 7 replacements. Still they do not always work. In some cases $search gives false positives or false negatives.
To clarify, I apply these changes while saving to the DB and not while retrieving from the DB.

Comment: If speed is really an issue, then you could apply this filter on *input*, so that it's only done once, rather than on output.

Comment: @El Yobo, I believe he already does that.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to indicate whether he does it on input or output; but if it was on input, where it's only done once, speed would seem to be less of an issue, so I am assuming that he's doing it on output.

Comment: @El Yobo, there are two hard-to-notice phrases where it is said - "*In a post transform to ...*" (in title; I believe "in a post" is POST request) and "*The system outputs HTML directly from the DB*". Anyway, it is really weird that there are performance problems because of those 2 functions. It might be worth giving some more info - contents of `$search` and `$replace`, size of `$str`, frequency of calling these functions, some timings.

Comment: @binary, yes, I see that's what he meant now :)  @brunoais, the average english word length is 5 characters; you get about 250 words to a page.  Your 1M characters is roughly equivalent to an 800 page book - are you really sure that it's worth worrying about things of that size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this code (*should be improved*):

```
function callback(array $matches) {
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($matches[0]);
}
$str = 'some <i>string</i> <b>with</b> tags '
     . '<a href="#">some link</a> '
     . '<img alt="" src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico"/><hr/>';
$str = htmlspecialchars($str);
$str = preg_replace_callback('#(&lt;(i|a)(?: .+?)?&gt;.*?&lt;/(\1)&gt;|&lt;(?:img)(?: .*?)?/&gt;)#', 'callback', $str);
echo $str;
```

Regular expression looks (*should look*) for 2 types of strings:

- `<tag attributes>content</tag>`, with `tag` part being the same for opening
  an closing tag, and `attributes` and `content` being optional
- `<tag attributes/>`, with `attributes` being optional

Tags are listed in `(i|a)` part for `<tag></tag>` types of tags and `(?:img)` for `<tag/>` types of tags.

If it finds matching tags, it passes content to `callback()` function which converts it back by using `htmlspecialchars_decode()`. This is necessary for decoding quotes and other encoded characters in the list of attributes.

I'm not sure if it works in all cases, i.e., if it matches all necessary tags. If this works in general, then pattern and `callback()` function should be improved so that `callback()` decodes only `<`, `>` characters and list of attributes; content of tags (i.e., `some link` part in `<a href='#'>some link</a>`) must not be decoded.

Comment: Ok, done and works. I used your idea. Corrected errors, substituted some stuff, adapted to be able to support tags inside tags, it does now less validation. It's a bit faster than str_replace() (having the account of the time spend creating the arrays). The purpose is not to care if the HTML is well written. It's only made to make shure that the allowed tags are displayed as HTML tags and not entities. Nice help thx.

Comment: Creating the arrays? If you're talking about arrays that are created for matches, you can use `?:` to avoid creating unnecessary arrays.

Comment: I mean, creating the arrays for the str_replace()

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` along with `htmlspecialchars` ISN'T slow.

Probabily you have some bottleneck somewhere else.

Comment: well... the main problem is that that method is also that it is really not reliable. I need something better to solve this problem. Specially if I work with tags with attributes... How can I solve the end tag substitutions?

Comment: the end tag substituitins? what's taht

Comment: @yes123 <a href="something" > How do I substitute the > in that correctly using str_replace?

Comment: `str_replace('>','what ever',$string);` ?

Comment: "end tag substituitins" means that both `<b>` and matching `</b>` must be replaced, rather than only opening tag `<b>`.

Comment: @yes123 so, you mean str_replace('&gt','>',$string);, huh? If that's so. What shall I so with: <body>, for instance? If I apply that to that tag it'll be a problem, no? I'll get an error in the HTML saved to the DB, no?

Comment: it's too hard to understand what you are saying :). Anyway with str_replace you can make any replace you want. If you need it just make some tests.

Comment: If accuracy rather than speed is your main concern, you might find [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) useful; it allows a lot of customisation of the permitted tags and it tidies up terrible user written HTML into valid HTML at the same time.  It's reasonably fast, but probably not for whole novels :)

Comment: that1's good for other uses. I'll save it for when I need it for using in other places (I have one where that1 is useful) Anyway thx for the link.